# Can't access wp-admin

Tags: wp-login-form

When trying to login one of my WP installs (regular WP 3.4.2-no multisite), I keep being redirected to the `wp-login.php` file.

I've checked nearly everything:

- Password is correct and changed...nothing
- Reset to a default theme...nothing
- Deactivated al plugins...nothing
- Reuploaded my `wp-login.php` file...nothing
- Checked the `.htaccess` files...nothing
- `wp-config.php` still looks the same.
- Erased my browser data and used an other browser... Still nothing.
- Completely overwritten every WordPress file with a fresh download install.

What else could this be? I didn't make any upgrades to the code.

Comment: Can you try a different browser? Highly unlikely it will help but you want to rule everything out in case a potential browser addon is causing an issue with cookies or referrers. Also is this problem new? Were you able to login at an earlier date? Or is this a newly installed blog/site?

Comment: @userabuser, tried that too. I'm working in Chrome, tried erasing all browser data, tried using Firefox, tried using the private browser mode... Nothing works.

Comment: For Panda sadness I recommend eating bamboo. That aside, can you answer the updated comment above (I added some additional questions).

Comment: Everything worked on before, we had an amazing weekend with 10K visitors each day. Since this morning, I can't login anymore, it's always looped back to wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2FXXXXX%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1 (site url editted to XXX)

Comment: try adding define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/'); see if this helps. What WP version are you on?

Comment: @DanielSachs That didn't work either. I'm on the latest WP 3.4.2, dutch language version install.

Comment: I fyou had recent registrations and you have a new user with the same usernicename it may also cause some cookie issues.

Comment: @DanielSachs No new registrations too. It's so bizar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by putting back a backup of the evening before the problem.The cause of this problem will never be known. Server logs (access and error logs) don't give a clue. WP_debug doesn't give a clue. Every FTP file has been checked and overwritten.

The problem must be in the database somehow, but the wp_options table shows no errors. Thanks for thinking with me. It's been a valuable lesson. I hope this topic can be a help for anyone facing the same problem. Normally the list in my question should solve their problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try this,

Open up your `wp-login.php` file and add the following `update_option` calls,

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
update_option('home', 'http://your.domain.name/the/path' );
```

beneath,

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

so... it should look like,

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.example.com/' );
update_option('home', 'http://www.example.com/' );
```

Where `http://www.example.com/` should match your domain.

1. **Then visit your login page.**
2. **Then remove the lines added to `wp-login.php`**

You might need to refresh your login page a couple of times or try and login a couple of times but it should let you in. Might be neccessary to clear your cache.

If all of a sudden,

```
http://www.example.com/
```

was appearing like,

```
http://example.com/ (no www - for example sake)
```

...then it might be causing this redirect loop issue you are having. Its easy to miss a slight change like that in your login URL as we often are not paying that close of attention.

So by running the `update_option` above we reset those paths to their original format.

***IF its not the above then make sure you definitely PURGE all of your browser cookies because there is a mismatch somewhere that's causing the issue. Has to be.***

Comment: Userabuser, thank you for your extended answer, but unfortunately it isn't solving the problem. Nothing changes in the URL. I've purged all my browser cookies several times, used the private browsing modus, used other browsers... I hope that I'm not far from the answer now. I'm replacing every WordPress file now. With a bit luck that might do the trick... Hopefully.

Comment: To clarify, you did try this method right? I.e. resetting the site and home URLs? Regardless of whether they appear to have changed or not.

Comment: I've added the two update option lines after the wp-load require. Visited the wp-login.php and tried to login. Removed the two lines, made a few hard refreshes and tried to log in again... Without any luck. By the way, none of my users can login at this moment... So it shouldn't be a single browser related problem, no?

Comment: Can you try adding `wp_clear_auth_cookie();` into the `wp-login.php` file (the function should be accessible there). Try and clear all authentication cookies. Then remove that line, revist `wp-login.php` and try logging in again.

Comment: Added right after the wp-load require, removed it after a single load and tried. No progress.

Comment: Try adding it to your `functions.php` file, in fact you can try both that and the `update_option` method via your `functions.php` file. To be certain the file fires, visit your front end, then try and login. Failing this I'm at a loss for an answer. Assuming you haven't been hacked, it should be along the lines of what I'm suggesting (there abouts). Unless anyone has an idea, it might be time for another pair of eyes to look at it. Its one thing to try and explain things, another if I were looking at it (I mean "I" in the metaphorical sense). Might be time to dig into your SQL databse...

Comment: It might be time indeed to dig in the SQL database, I've overwritten every WordPress file, changed the theme to the 2010 theme, deleted all plugins... And still it's not working. Any clues where I could look in the database (wp_options looks ok)? I don't think it's hacked, since there are no traces or references left.

Comment: Look at `siteurl` and `home` under `wp_options` table. Also look at `rewrite_rules` to see if there is any rogue rewrites causing issue. Could also be some transients causing the issue too (but this might be more unlikely). Another option is to programatically create another user and try their login credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

- if your website is on 'https'
- if you use custom login form to login

be sure to set `$secure_cookie` to `true` in
`wp_signon( $credentials, $secure_cookie )`

I had same problem, user is logged in on front end, but if you try to reach wp-admin, you get redirected to login page and need to login again.

Comment: Hi Bobz - your solution is only working in my case - I test all other solutions, but only adding wp_signon( $credentials, $secure_cookie ) instead of wp_signon( '', $secure_cookie ) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen to me and I have looked all over the web for answers and surprisingly no one has mentioned the idea that your site could have been compromised as mine had been.

First, via ftp, check the dates your files have been last updated. This should help you identify what those files may be.

If you have been compromised, the two quickest places to check...
 your index.php and your wp-login.php file

Look for this code: `eval(base64_decode())`

If you see this - you have been hacked and need to remove all instances of this throughout your site. I came across a pretty good tutorial on how to clean an entire site [here](http://raamdev.com/2013/cleaning-evalbase64_decode-from-a-hacked-wordpress-website-via-ssh/)

Once your site has been cleaned, you should be all good to login again, but I would recommend changing all names and passwords as your hack could be more malicious.